# Deploying lightning app Using Ant throws Error: In field: utilityBar - no FlexiPage named "test_UtilityBar" found

Tags: ant

I got Following when I retrieve The app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
        <content>TEST_Case_LEX_Page</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <pageOrSobjectType>Case</pageOrSobjectType>
    </actionOverrides>
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#0070D2</headerColor>
        <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>false</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
    </brand>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>false</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
    <isNavPersonalizationDisabled>false</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
    <label>TEST</label>
    <navType>Console</navType>
    <tabs>standard-home</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Account</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Contact</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Case</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-report</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Dashboard</tabs>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
    <utilityBar>TEST_UtilityBar</utilityBar>
    <workspaceConfig>
        <mappings>
            <tab>standard-Account</tab>
        </mappings>
        <mappings>
            <tab>standard-Case</tab>
        </mappings>
        <mappings>
            <tab>standard-Contact</tab>
        </mappings>
        <mappings>
            <tab>standard-Dashboard</tab>
        </mappings>
        <mappings>
            <tab>standard-home</tab>
        </mappings>
        <mappings>
            <tab>standard-report</tab>
        </mappings>
    </workspaceConfig>
</CustomApplication>
```

And When I deploy This App i Get Following Error

Error: In field: utilityBar - no FlexiPage named "test_UtilityBar" found

Comment: Hi I get the same issue. Did you find a resolve to this?

Answer (score 0):

A utility bar is a space in lightning apps where you can load aura components.

If you go to your lightning app config you can see it in the Utility Items (Desktop Only) slot:
Setup --> App Manager --> [Your app name] --> Edit
[image]

It seems to me that either your package or the org where you are trying to deploy that package misses an Aura or Lightning component named Test_UtilityBar

You have several options:

- Remove that component from the utility bar, retrieve and deploy the package
- Add Test_UtilityBar component to the package.xml
- Create an aura component in the target org with the name Test_UtilityBar, so your app will find a matching component for the tag

Please, let me know if it helps you

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Along with the application you have to deploy it's dependent component.
Here, it's Utility bar. The naming convention of the utility bar is - <application_name>_UtilityBar
And you will find this under flexipage folder.
For you it should be `TEXT_UtilityBar.flexipage-meta.xml`
Including TEST_UtilityBar.flexipage-meta.xml metadata should work.

Regards,
Parag